# how to play a swf background music on a website with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to play an swf file that contains sound only (so I can have background music on a website). I want to load that swf with javascript and not embeded it.

How do I do that?

I have found this code:

```
<embed
    src="melodyloops-sounds-swf-player.swf"
    width="25"
    height="16"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowfullscreen="false"
    flashvars="filename=low-down.swf&volume=0&backcolor=ffffff&maincolor=00648C&timeplay=0"
/>
```

but I dont know how to make this swf play only when the function is called!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
    {
        if (window.document[movieName]) 
        {
            return window.document[movieName];
        }
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
        {
            if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
                return document.embeds[movieName]; 
        }
        else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
        { 
            return document.getElementById(movieName);
        }
    }

    function PlayFlashMovie()
    {
        var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("PUT-YOUR-FLASH-ID-HERE");
        flashMovie.Play();
        var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("PUT-YOUR-FLASH-ID-HERE");
        flashMovie.Play();
        var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("PUT-YOUR-FLASH-ID-HERE");
        flashMovie.Play();
    }
</script>
```

Then make sure you have specified the names and id's for your flash elements so that the javascript can reference them. Pu an id="" field in the  field, and the name="" in the  tag.

Comment: can you help with the name and id thing? i dont get itO_o

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use use SWFObject which allows you to embed Flash on the fly when a javascript function is called:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/